# ThreadPoolExecutor : Pull out hanged tasks

Tags: java, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

I have implemented ThreadPoolExecutor to invoke a task.
And It seems tasks got hanged on I/O because of the core/queue size misconfiguration.
I want to pull the hanging thread out
so that the other threads in my queue starts executing.

Is there any way to list the threads inside a threadpoolexecutor and pull out the hanging thread?

Answer (score 0):

You have control over the used executor, you could use the ThreadPoolExecutor's beforeExecute and afterExecute methods to keep track of running tasks and use that to create a getActiveTasks method.

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.*;


public class ActiveTasksThreadPool extends ThreadPoolExecutor {

private final ConcurrentHashMap<Runnable, Boolean> activeTasks = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public ActiveTasksThreadPool(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize, long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit, BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue) {
    super(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue);
}

@Override
protected void beforeExecute(Thread t, Runnable r) {

    activeTasks.put(r, Boolean.TRUE);
    super.beforeExecute(t, r);
}

@Override
protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {

    super.afterExecute(r, t);
    activeTasks.remove(r);
}

public Set<Runnable> getActiveTasks() {
    // the returned set will not throw a ConcurrentModificationException.
    return activeTasks.keySet();
}
```

In order to set a timeout on thread tasks with `Future`:

```
 ActiveTasksThreadPool executor = new ActiveTasksThreadPool(maxTasks, maxTasks, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>());Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

      List<Future<Integer>> resultList = new ArrayList<>();

      Random random = new Random();

      for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
      {
          Integer number = random.nextInt(10);
          FactorialCalculator calculator  = new FactorialCalculator(number);
          Future<Integer> result = executor.submit(calculator);
          result .get(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); // here is a timeout of 100 milisecond
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This should be already implemented right?
I have my java process running with queued tasks in a ThreadPoolExecutor.
Is there any way to pull of the hanged thread out of the already running process

Comment: @user3180467 you should use a timeout mechanism for that, I've updated my answer